# How to convert framework in a cocapod?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

I have create new cocoa-pod with an example project which in original project used a framework (X.framework).
So it was like:
Original_Proj
|- four Classes (A,B,C,D{.h,.m})
|-Main.m
|- etc by default xcode project files
|-X.framework

Now those four classes imported the X.framework and used its functionality. (Purpose being only few classes of framework exposed project).

========================================================================
Now in a xcworkspace created by cocoapod, i have added all the Four classes and other necc. files in **EXAMPLE folder** but now i want the X.framework to be as Development pod so i can import it in those Classes in cocoapod embed project.
Following is my Cocopod project structure[image: Cocopod project structure]

Now i wanted to ask whether i have to put the complete framework it self in Dev. pods folder **OR** all X.framework's source files in Dev. pods folder. Will it expose those files to others if they install the pod in their project? Please guide with proper way if I am doing something wrong? Detail explanation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that pod. follow the below steps

1) Open terminal

2) sudo gem install cocoapods (gem will get installed in Ruby inside 
System library)

3) pod setup

4) create a xcode project

5) cd "path to your project root directory"

6) pod init

7) open -a Xcode Podfile (podfile will get open in text mode. Initially it will be empty put  the following line of  code.)

8) pod frame_name veraion (It’s finally time to add your first dependency using CocoaPods! Copy and paste the following into your pod file, right after target "Project" do:)

Comment: Does those steps enable Xcode Project to use Other cocoa pods ?

Comment: why you need use another cocoa pod. using same pod file for another framework

Comment: I actually donot want to use cocapod in that XCODE project. I wish to make a cocoapod with my X.framwork. Will those steps perform the required?

Comment: if you want cocopod within you project, this steps are necessary